# Prepopulate Sprout Form using an entry

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, craft-pro

I'm outputting a Sprout form on my site so that users can request an update to their profile using the short code

```
{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm('updateStoreDetails') }}
```

I would like to pre-populate the form with information from the current entry object in the template. I tried to do something like this...

```
{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm('updateStoreDetails', {
    "fields": {
        "memberId": {
            "value": 12345
        },
        "name": {
            "value": "Michael"
        }
    }
}) }}
```

but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

A solution is now available in the Sprout Forms documentation: [Example > Pre-populating a Field](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/pre-populating-a-field).